# What does frequency stability of an harmonic oscillator mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, measurements

I don't understand the term in a paper which says that quality factor $Q$ is the inverse of the damping and indicates how sharp the resonance in frequency is. So they use the $Q$ as a proxy metric for frequency stability. They say that the frequency stability is the robins formula[image] from the AFM community. I don't understand what they mean here with stability. Do they mean that the  short-term instabilities of oscillators show these random fluctuations which have a small magnitude? And what does a narrow-band frequency modulation, and the result is a spreading of the oscillator signal spectrum mean?

Cite as:arXiv:1710.11280

Answer (score 1):

A simple and rather intuitive model of an oscillator is a wide bandwidth amplifier whose output is fed back into its input using a resonator (band-pass filter). Oscillation is induced by noise that will be amplified and then reamplified by the (positive) feedback while the amplitude increases until the amplifier reaches saturation.

The oscillation can only happen at frequencies that are in the pass band of the resonator because that limits the frequencies that can be fed back to the amplifier input. If there is a wide range of frequencies that can be fed back one loses control over the oscillation and the output frequency may wander around due to variation in temperature, humidity, etc., and is also noisy. Besides the frequency/phase noise, both short term and long term, the wandering also contributes to spurious amplitude noise as it moves in the pass band of the resonator.

See, Leeson:"A Simple Model of Feedback Oscillator Noise Spectrum", https://doi.org/10.1109/PROC.1966.4682